# Adding Light Falloff for multiple Point Lights

Tags: directx, hlsl, lighting

I'm currently trying to add multiple point lights to my game. What I have done appears to be mostly working, except for a small problem of blending light falloff. Here's two images to show you what's happening. In the first one, Light Falloff is commented out. Both point lights appear correctly.

[image]

And here's the second image, where I have light falloff enabled. You will see that only light #2 is "mostly" visible. There are traces of light #1, but for the most part, light #1 appears to be overridden by light #2's falloff. In other words, each consecutive light's falloff overrides the light from previous lights.

[image]

Does anyone know how to add falloff for multiple point lights? I'm sure I'm doing something slightly wrong, and that's why the lights are not properly accumulated.

Here's my shader:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXTURE;
    float3 norm : NORMAL;
};

struct PixelShaderArgs
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 col : TEXTURE;
    float3 norm : NORMAL;
    float3 worldPos : POSITION;
};

struct PointLightShaderArgs
{
    float3 pos;
    float radius;
    float intensity;
    float3 padding;
    float4 ambient;
    float4 diffuse;
};

Texture2D ShaderTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState Sampler : register(s0);

float4x4 localMatrix : register(b0);
cbuffer ShaderDataBuffer : register(b1)
{
    float2 TextureResolution;
};
cbuffer cbPerFrame : register(b3)
{
    PointLightShaderArgs light[8];
};

cbuffer WorldPositionBuffer : register(b4)
{
    float4x4 World;
};

PixelShaderArgs VertexShaderMain(Vertex vertex)
{
    PixelShaderArgs output;
    output.pos = mul(vertex.pos, localMatrix);
    output.col = vertex.tex;
    output.norm = mul(vertex.norm, World);
    output.worldPos = mul(vertex.pos, World);
    return output;
}

int2 convertUVToPixel(float u, float v)
{
    int width = TextureResolution.x;
    int height = TextureResolution.y;
    int xCoordinate = floor(u * width);
    int yCoordinate = floor(v * height);
    return int2(xCoordinate % width, yCoordinate % height);
}

float Falloff(float distance, float radius)
{
    return clamp(1.0f - (distance / radius), 0.0, 1.0);
}

#define ATTENUATION_CONSTANT 1.0f // 0% Constant
#define ATTENUATION_LINEAR 0.0f // 100% Linear
#define ATTENUATION_QUADRATIC 0.0f // 100% Quadratic


float4 PixelShaderMain(PixelShaderArgs pixelShaderArgs) : SV_Target
{
    float u = pixelShaderArgs.col.x;
    float v = pixelShaderArgs.col.y;
    // Lighting
    float3 fragColor = float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float4 diffuse = ShaderTexture.Load(int3(convertUVToPixel(u, v), 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        
        
        float3 ambient = diffuse * light[i].ambient;
        pixelShaderArgs.norm = normalize(pixelShaderArgs.norm);
        float3 lightToPixelVec = light[i].pos - pixelShaderArgs.worldPos;
        float distance = length(lightToPixelVec);
        float luminosity = dot(lightToPixelVec / distance, pixelShaderArgs.norm);
        float intensity = 1.00f;
        if (luminosity > 0.0f)
        {
        
            // Do lighting attenuation
            fragColor += luminosity * diffuse * light[i].diffuse;
            fragColor /= ATTENUATION_CONSTANT + (ATTENUATION_LINEAR * distance) + (ATTENUATION_QUADRATIC * (distance * distance));
            fragColor *= light[i].intensity; // multiply the final result by the intensity.
            fragColor *= Falloff(distance, light[i].radius); // This is what's causing the problem!!
            //fragColor = saturate(fragColor + ambient);
        }
        
    }
    return float4(fragColor, diffuse.a);
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. The solution was to move the falloff calculation up and inline it with the following line: `fragColor += luminosity * diffuse * light[i].diffuse * Falloff(distance,light[i].radius);`

This results the correcting falloff blending, shown in this picture:
[image]

and another picture showing three overlapped point lights:

[image]

Here's the updated shader (A lot of changes were made from the first one because I'm actually posting this answer late)

```
struct Vertex
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXTURE;
    float3 norm : NORMAL;
};

struct PixelShaderArgs
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 col : TEXTURE;
    float3 norm : NORMAL;
    float3 worldPos : POSITION;
};

struct PointLightShaderArgs
{
    float3 pos;
    float radius;
    float intensity;
    float3 padding;
    float4 ambient;
    float4 diffuse;
};

Texture2D ShaderTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState Sampler : register(s0);

float4x4 localMatrix : register(b0);
cbuffer ShaderDataBuffer : register(b1)
{
    float2 TextureResolution;
};
cbuffer cbPerFrame : register(b3)
{
    PointLightShaderArgs light[32];
};

cbuffer WorldPositionBuffer : register(b4)
{
    float4x4 World;
};

PixelShaderArgs VertexShaderMain(Vertex vertex)
{
    PixelShaderArgs output;
    output.pos = mul(vertex.pos, localMatrix);
    output.col = vertex.tex;
    output.norm = mul(vertex.norm, World);
    output.worldPos = mul(vertex.pos, World);
    return output;
}

int2 convertUVToPixel(float u, float v)
{
    int width = TextureResolution.x;
    int height = TextureResolution.y;
    int xCoordinate = floor(u * width);
    int yCoordinate = floor(v * height);
    return int2(xCoordinate % width, yCoordinate % height);
}

float Falloff(float distance, float radius)
{
    return clamp(1.0f - (distance / radius), 0.0, 1.0);
}

#define ATTENUATION_CONSTANT 1.0f // 0% Constant
#define ATTENUATION_LINEAR 0.0f // 100% Linear
#define ATTENUATION_QUADRATIC 0.0f // 100% Quadratic; Democrats are domestic terrorists


float4 PixelShaderMain(PixelShaderArgs pixelShaderArgs) : SV_Target
{
    float u = pixelShaderArgs.col.x;
    float v = pixelShaderArgs.col.y;
    // Lighting
    float3 fragColor = float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float4 diffuse = ShaderTexture.Load(int3(convertUVToPixel(u, v), 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        
        
        float3 ambient = diffuse * light[i].ambient;
        pixelShaderArgs.norm = normalize(pixelShaderArgs.norm);
        float3 lightToPixelVec = light[i].pos - pixelShaderArgs.worldPos;
        float distance = length(lightToPixelVec);
        float luminosity = dot(lightToPixelVec / distance, pixelShaderArgs.norm);
        float intensity = 1.00f;
        if (luminosity > 0.0f)
        {
        
            // Do lighting attenuation
            fragColor += luminosity * diffuse * light[i].diffuse * Falloff(distance,light[i].radius);
            fragColor /= ATTENUATION_CONSTANT + (ATTENUATION_LINEAR * distance) + (ATTENUATION_QUADRATIC * (distance * distance));
            fragColor *= light[i].intensity; // multiply the final result by the intensity.
            
        }
        fragColor = saturate(fragColor + ambient);
        
    }
    return float4(fragColor, diffuse.a);
        
}
```